# How to pronounce Zengyang?

Tags: pronunciation

My friend's Chinese name is Zengyang and I want to surprise her by being able to pronounce it properly when she visits me in a few weeks.

Comment: There are four tones for every Chinese syllable, so could you provide her name in Chinese Characters? So we could better help you :)

Comment: Are you looking for the IPA or an sound clip for this? I am not sure how to 'describe' a sound to you? The 'z' doesn't exist in English, so there is no way to describe it using the English phonology. If you want the IPA, it's easy enough to look it up on WP. Here is the 'z'. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_dental_sibilant_affricate#Voiceless_alveolar_fronted_sibilant_affricate Also as @ChineseHulu.com mentioned, you did not specify the tones. Best way to do this? Listen to the way your friend pronounces it including where she places her tongue.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a bit of a wild guess - but we don't really have much to work with do we now...

for the first part of your friends name you can take a look here:
[曾](http://dict.baidu.com/s?wd=%E6%9B%BE) and click the audio button next to `[zēng]`
(this *most* likely is the correct pronunciation for the first part of your friends name)

Yang is most likely a second-tone (again best guess)
so you can have a look here:
[阳](http://dict.baidu.com/s?wd=%E9%98%B3) and click the audio button next to `[yáng]`

This is the best I can do you for.